# Make Google Keep a startup application

Tags: google, startup-applications

I am on Ubuntu 20.04

I can see Google Keep in my app tray. How can I set Google Keep as my startup application?

I don't know what command needs to be added in '*Startup Applications*'. 
I looked in `/usr/share/applications` folder to find Google Keep, but it's not present there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

Comment: No, I checked that post already and there is a place I am stuck. I am not able to find the app in my application folder so that I can look at what command need to be added

Comment: I assume it's a Google Chrome app. Then it should be in `~/.local/share/applications/` instead (with a long and weird name).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a simpler way to do this.

*GNOME Tweaks* has an option for selecting the application you want to run during startup.